# "Сакральный артефакт грядущей миссии"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> На наших глазах его захлестнула волна какого-то глубокого чувства.
>   Что-то предстояло важное сделать теперь. Эта открыточка была не просто
>   безликим приглашением на выставку, но изображённое на ней явилось
>   сакральным артефактом грядущей миссии. Старый клоун благодарственно
>   понял глаза на миссис Кенгуру и по-настоящему, растроганно сказал:
>   "Спасибо вам! Большое спасибо!"

Точку после кавычек не предлагать, остальные знаки (вкупе с лексикой) благосклонно будут нами рассмотрены.

Comment: Мудрёно... 1. Описка: "поДнял глаза". 2. Запятая после "по-настоящему" не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за "понял". Называется "глазнушка". Корректорский брак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Эта открыточка была не просто безликим приглашением на выставку —  изображённое на ней сделало ее сакральным артефактом грядущей миссии.**

**Артефакт** — это (в данном случае) рукотворный **предмет** с особыми свойствами (священными, магическими).

**Сакра́льное** (от англ. sacral и лат. sacrum — священное, посвященное Богу) — в широком смысле — всё, имеющее отношение к божественному, **религиозному**, небесному, потустороннему, иррациональному, **мистическому,** отличающееся от обыденных вещей, понятий, явлений.

**Магический артефакт —** некая рукотворная вещь, которая обладает магическими свойствами в результате воздействия на нее... Но при этом к магическим артефактам относят только рукотворные предметы, то есть например камни, обладающие магическими свойствами просто в силу своей природы, артефактами не являются. Если обратиться к этимологии, то это слово — артефакт — произошло от латинских arte (“искусственный”) и factus (“созданный” или “сделанный”). Таким образом, речь идет о созданных человеком вещах с определенной (в нашем случае магической) целью. https://happywitch.ru/blog/magicheskie-artefakty-spisok/

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что таким артефактом могла быть только *сама открытка* (обычно это законченный *предмет*, хотя может быть и отделяемый слой наскальной живописи). В остальном - излишне напыщенно и читается неудобно, но расшифровать можно, в отличие от пресловутой "виньетки ложной сути".